# Highcharts: update series on multiple charts with same data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two Highcharts which have no data in the series when they are created. In a later step these charts are filled via the update-function. The first time I do this, all works perfectly ("First Data"-Button in fiddle).

If I repeat this step with other data, only the first Chart is updating correctly ("New Data-Button in fiddle).

http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCross82/v34fn2zj/

Can someone explain why the second chart is not updating? Maybe I'm just missing something?

```
<body>
<button onclick="firstData()">First Data</button>
<button onclick="newData()">New Data</button>

<div id="chart1" style="height: 300px"></div>
<div id="chart2" style="height: 300px"></div>
</body>

<script>
var chart1;
var chart2;

chart1 = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
  series: [{
    data: [],
  }, {
    data: [],
  }]
});

chart2 = Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
  series: [{
    data: [],
  }, {
    data: [],
  }]
});

function firstData() {
  var series1 = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
  var series2 = [4, 4, 1, 2, 0];
  updateChart(series1, series2);
}

function newData() {
  var series1 = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4];
  var series2 = [2, 1, 1, 1, 0];
  updateChart(series1, series2);
}

function updateChart(series1, series2){
  chart1.update({
    series: [{
      data: series1
    }, {
      data: series2
    }]
  });

  chart2.update({
    series: [{
      data: series1
    }, {
      data: series2
    }]
  });
  console.log(series1, series2);
}
</script>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well I faced the same problem, but I'm unable to recall the solution :)

Comment: thats really strange...
as a workaround it works when you split the updateChart function and only update one chart within one function call.
Or if you recreate the arrays in the function like this: data: [...series1]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain in more detail how the array has to look like?

Comment: The last example @AxelM mentions would be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v34fn2zj/59/

Comment: Unfortunately this is not supported in Internet Explorer. But it seems to work with: "data: series1.slice()" http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCross82/v34fn2zj/67/

Answer (score 3):

For better performance Highcharts use reference to `data` and mutate `options.data` object. So, when the first chart is updated, the second has already changed options and `update` does not cause any effect. The solution is to do not use the same object:

```
function updateChart(series1, series2){
  chart1.update({
    series: [{
      data: series1
    }, {
      data: series2
    }]
  });

  chart2.update({
    series: [{
      data: series1.slice()
    }, {
      data: series2.slice()
    }]
  });
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wov6k8ye/

This problem is reported on Highcharts github, but it is not marked as a bug: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9294